# PHP curl() get all header at one time

Tags: php, redirect, curl

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://fb.com';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    ));
    $header = explode("\n", curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r($header);
```

Result

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.facebook.com/?_rdr
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
X-FB-Debug: rVg0o+qDt9z/zJu7jTW1gi1WSRC8YIMu3e6XnPagx39zZ4pbV0k2yrNfZmkdTLZyfzg713X+M0Lr2jS2P018xA==
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 08:48:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

But I want to get all `Location` at one time

```
I enter > http://fb.com

then 301 redirect: http://www.facebook.com/?_rdr

then 302 redirect: https://www.facebook.com/
```

I want to get All this link at one time with status `301` `302`

or any better idea to get redirect location url . THANKS

Comment: Do you need the intermediate locations or are you just interested in the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all headers from every request made until no `Location` header is sent using this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$headers = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But then, you'll have to extract the information yourself because `$headers` is only a string, not an array.

If you only need the last location, simply do `curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL)`.

Comment: That's all the response headers....   any way to get all the request headers? `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);` only seems to return the final request.

Answer (score 0):

Use [curl_getinfo()](http://php.net/curl_getinfo) to check if you got a 301 or 302 response and then repeat the same code again as long as that's the case. So, put your code in a function like:

```
$headers = array();

function getHeaders($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    ));
    $header = explode("\n", curl_exec($curl));

    if (in_array(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE), array(301, 302))) {
        // Got a 301 or 302, store this stuff and do it again
        $headers[] = $header;
        curl_close($curl);
        return getHeaders($url);
    }

    $headers[] = $header;
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Then `$headers` will hold all the headers encountered up until the first non-301/302 response.